# Network Unclaimed intel wifi 6 AX210/AX201 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, drivers, iwlwifi

For a project i needed to work on ubuntu 16.04, unfortunately i cant access wifi rn i'm using usb tethering for internet but for project in need wifi.

I tried to manually update 5.1 as for these driver 5.1 required by [intel](https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and it too didn't works, so installed 16.04 as fresh
According to Intel, Intel® WI-Fi 6 AX210/201 160MHz device is only guaranteed to work with the kernel version 5.1+.

I have tried these before:
tried both the answers from this:
[Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217719/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

looked in to this:
[Intel WiFi 6 AX210 not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295662/intel-wifi-6-ax210-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

These are results for commands:

Command: `lshw -C Network`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:601d174000-601d177fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u4
       serial: ce:83:66:99:4c:7a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.118.22 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output
```

Command:`rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Command:  `modinfo iwlwifi | grep file`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-142-generic/updates/dkms/iwlwifi.ko
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
```

Command:  `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    3.804310] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    3.804310] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
[    3.852062] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    3.852076] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852088] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852093] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852104] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852109] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852124] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852134] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852139] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852144] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852149] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.852150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.852152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-39
[    3.852153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-52
[    3.852154] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Can somebody provide code guidance? thanks very much!

Comment: Are you saying Ubuntu 16.04 has the kernel version you need?

Comment: @JaromandaX for ax210 its stated it need kernel 5.1+ but in 16.04 it is 4.15, i updated to 5.1 but still no result so switched back to 4.15